# If I want to insert many records in one record from other table, how can I do that?

Tags: android, sqlite

Alright, my situation was like this:

My database have two tables, one of the table is named `DB_TABLE`, which is used to store some claim records, which contains the following fields: `claimdate`, `claimtype`, `claimcurrency`, `claimcost`, `claimdescription`.

In my other table, which is named `DBATTACHMENT_TABLE`, is used to store images, and the field name is `claimattachment`.

The record table updates when I hit the submit button, and in the meantime, I wish I could updates my attachment table as well. But if I need to add more than 1 attachment in each record, I need a parent ID to create relationship between two tables. How can I get which row I was creating at the record table before I hit the submit button, so that I can insert the parent ID into my attachment table at the same time? Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that, you also need to add an **ID** to the `DB_TABLE` which is of type `AUTOINCREMENT`, at first create a add a row in the `DB_TABLE`. After adding it, make a select query to the table for the last row, and you will get the **ID** from `DB_TABLE` and using that **ID** continue with your attachment table operation.

Comment: Thanks, I just found that I can use the following command after my insert-into-db_table method:
Cursor c = claiminfoDB.rawQuery("SELECT last_insert_rowid() FROM " + DB_TABLE, null);
c.moveToFirst();
int parentID = c.getInt(0); // Since the cursor only got 1 result

Comment: @JohnnyCheuk While `.rawQuery()` will do what you need, please, read/understand the CRUD (create, restore, update, delete) model related to a database, and use the appropriate method. This will help against most SQL injections, as well as make your program easier to maintain. (And should you relay a lot on databases, even make it faster.. [the `claiminfoDB.insert()` should be the one that tells you the ID](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29)

Comment: @Bonatti Thanks for the advice!